# How is $ P(-\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}) = P(X \leq \sqrt{y}) - P(X < -\sqrt{y})$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus

I recently started studying elementary statistics and I stumbled upon this in my book:

[image]

But I dont understand how $ P(-\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}) = P(X \leq \sqrt{y}) - P(X < -\sqrt{y})$. Could you help me understand what is happening here?

---

**Attempt to understand:**

$ P(-\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}) = P((-\sqrt{y} \leq X) \ \cap \ (X\leq \sqrt{y}))$ but ***I dont understand how AND ( $\cap$ ) becomes minus or plus here.***

---

I know that:
$$ F_X(x) = P(X \leq x) $$
Where F is cumulative distribution function. X is random variable and P is probability.

Comment: For $a<b$, we have $(-\infty,b] = (-\infty,a] \cup (a,b],$ a union of disjoint intervals, so take the probability of each side and rearrange.

Comment: It's quite easy to see if you draw a picture and consider areas under a graph

Answer (score 2):

This picture illustrates what was said in the comments to your question. Let $z=\sqrt{y}$.
[image]